# Error after upgrade MySQL 5.0 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-error-1055

I have upgraded MySQL from version 5.0.67 to 5.7.19. But every time I run MySQL query, I get this error.

> [Err] 1055 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'information_schema.PROFILING.SEQ' which is not functionally dependent
>   on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I have checked to the PROFILING table in information_schema database, but it contains no data.

My MySQL sql_mode is ANSI.

Comment: From 5.7 the full_group_by is set as default. You can learn more on the below link. You can also change this setting.
`https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html`

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: @Ryosaku Every query I run. Like this usual query also get this error.
`SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: @Krishnakumar That link is page not found.

Comment: @conan_flow :: Please google how to unset 'only_full_group_by'

Comment: @Krishnakumar I have change my sql mode from ANSI to REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE.
Actually, ANSI mode include REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.
Thank you for helping me. You can post it as answer.

Comment: @conan_flow : Posted!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the SQL mode :

Remove the 'only_full_group_by' option. For MySQL 5.7 this is set as Default.

Comment: For additional, if you are using ANSI mysql_mode, you can change it to  `REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE`  in my.ini to disable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.